# Docker volume conflict

Tags: docker

I have a dockerized web application that I'm running in a [HA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability) setup. I have a cron setup that runs [`dockup`](https://github.com/tutumcloud/dockup) every midnight to backup my important information stored on other containers. Now I would like to backup and aggregate my logs from my web application too. Problem is, how do I that? If I use the `VOLUME` key in Dockerfile to expose `/logs` to the host machine, there would be a collision because there would be two `/logs` directories on the `dockup` container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked dockup. It does not have a /logs directory. Seems it uses /var/logs for log output.

```
$ docker run -it --name dockup borja/dockup bash
```

Otherwise, yes it would be a problem because the volume will be mounted under the mentioned name and also the current container processes will log to the folder. Not good.

- Use a logging container like fluentd. In this [tutorial](http://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/docker-logging) it also offers writing to S3 buckets like dockup. Tutorial can be founder [here](http://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/docker-logging).
- Tweak your container, e.g. with symbolic links to log or relay the log to a different volume.
- Access log not through containers but native docker and copy it to S3 yourself or running dockup on your local mounted log file.

  ```
  $ docker logs container/name > logfile.log
  $ docker run --rm \
    --env-file env.txt \
    -v $(pwd)/logfile.log:/customlogs/logfile.txt \
    --name dockup borja/dockup
  ```

  > Now you can take the folder /customlogs/ as your backup path inside the env.txt.